# Debugging console for stand-alone web app on iOS

Tags: ios, debugging, html, mobile-safari

When testing my web app on the iPad, I can enable the debugging console of Safari Mobile and happily read my logging output. I can not find a way to do the same for a stand-alone app, meaning the web app was "added to the home screen" and the window.navigator.standalone flag says true, but there is no "Debug Console" banner at the top like there is inside Safari Mobile.

I have a bug that only happens in stand-alone mode and am almost ready to add a little debugging console to my web app, or worse, go to the dreaded alert debugging method.

So, SO, any awSOme ideas?

Comment: Even I'm facing similar issue. Could you let me know if you were able to debug the stand-alone app. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47713639/debugging-web-apps-added-to-home-screen-on-ios-safari

Comment: Yes, I remember that remote debugging via Safari worked like a charm and is definitely the way to go. Have you tried the steps in the second link in the accepted answer?

Comment: Ya, I tried it but no luck. When opened the app on iOS Safari, I was able to debug. When I added the app to home screen, Safari did not detect the app. In the develop menu, i was getting 'No Inspectable Applications'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use http://www.iwebinspector.com - only for ios5 and up though..

for ios6 you can use safari6 and remote debugging http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/

if you are not on mac or want true remote debug, you can use [jsconsole.com](http://jsconsole.com)

Comment: Any ideas for someone who isn't using a Mac? ( I hope not, because I'm using this opportunity to request my boss get me a mac...)

Comment: jsconsole might work out for you - http://jsconsole.com/remote-debugging.html

Comment: jsconsole doesn't support remote debug any more. Details: https://github.com/remy/jsconsole/issues/101

Use https://remotejs.com/ instead