# different CSS behaviour on iphone's safari after visiting website from home screen

Tags: iphone, css, safari

I am having a hard time with website http://m.crossfitbratislava.sk. when testing on PC/MAC, everything works fine. When I launch website in safari - looks the same.

The problem appears, when I save the website to my Home-screen & launch it from there. Whole website layout is destroyed.

I think it has something to do with Fullscreen mode but I can't figure out what I should do to get rid of it.

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: Have you tried changing from `<style type="text/css" media="screen">@import "../assets/css/jqtouch.css";</style>` to the normal style call `<style type="text/css" href="../assets/css/jqtouch.css" />`? Btw, the "differences" that OP didn't told: Seems logo is floated (out of the div), when changing page the footer gets somewhere in the layout, etc.

Comment: good point with css definition, but it didn't help

Comment: All I could find about debugging standalone websites was this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071022/debugging-console-for-stand-alone-web-app-on-ios Don't have a Mac to test :/

Answer (score 0):

so I fixed it by setting fullscreen mode in JQT variable to false. now when it is launch via desktop icon, it has url bar like it is being opened with safari

```
var jQT = new $.jQTouch({
                addGlossToIcon: false,
                startupScreen: 'loading_logo.PNG',
                statusBar: 'black-translucent',
                themeSelectionSelector: '#jqt #themes ul',
                fullScreen: false,
                preloadImages: []
            });
```